# How to include pages in web-inf from outer directory

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I want to to include some pages(header.jsp and footer.jsp) in my index.jsp. Problem is I don't know how to give a link to them. Below code in index.jsp gives error;

```
<s:include value="/web-inf/header.jsp"></s:include>
```

it gives;

```
cannot resolve servlet /web-inf/header.jsp.
```

My directory list(web-inf and index.jsp are in same directory.);

```
/web-inf
    /web-inf/header.jsp
    /web-inf/footer.jsp
/index.jsp
```

Comment: You should include how *specifically* you're trying to use and/or include them, otherwise we're guessing.

Comment: @DaveNewton there was a mistake with my editing sorry :)

Comment: *What* is the error? Is it actually named `web-inf`, which is wrong, or is it named `WEB-INF`, which is right?

Comment: @DaveNewton both gives same error. Error is not about capital laters.

Comment: I'd still recommend actually using the correct name, though. And why use the Struts 2 tag when you can just use the JSTL tag? It's generally recommended to use JSTL when functionality overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include file from `web-inf` folder, you may try this:

```
<s:include value="../web-inf/header.jsp"/>
```

`../` - go to the parent of `index.jsp` and `web-inf`.